# Calling a variable that is nowhere else

Tags: php

In the following code, from *[Beginning PHP and mySQL 5e](https://github.com/Apress/beginning-php-and-mysql-5e/blob/master/9-1.php)*, if `acronym` function is called without mentioning `$matches`, how ,in the definition of `acronym`, `$matches` is never linked to anything, but rather used in the `isset($acronym[$matches[1]]))` ?, How `isset` knows what is `$matches` in the first place?

The following is the code and I have tested that it is working.
I just cannot follow up with the use of an arbitrary term; `$matches`, and its use.

```
    // This function will add the acronym's long form
// directly after any acronyms found in $matches
function acronym($matches) {
    $acronyms = array(
        'WWW' => 'World Wide Web',
        'IRS' => 'Internal Revenue Service',
        'PDF' => 'Portable Document Format');
    if (isset($acronyms[$matches[1]]))
        return $acronyms[$matches[1]] . " (" . $matches[1] . ")";
    else
        return $matches[1];
}
// The target text
$text = "The <acronym>IRS</acronym> offers tax forms in
         <acronym>PDF</acronym> format on the <acronym>WWW</acronym>.";
// Add the acronyms' long forms to the target text
$newtext = preg_replace_callback("/<acronym>(.*)<\/acronym>/U", 'acronym',
                                  $text);
print_r($newtext);
```

The output is:

`The Internal Revenue Service (IRS) offers tax forms inPortable Document Format (PDF) format on the World Wide Web (WWW).`

Reminder: The input, for the function preg_replace_callback is:

`The <acronym>IRS</acronym> offers tax forms in <acronym>PDF</acronym> format on the <acronym>WWW</acronym>.`

Comment: `$matches` is a _required_ parameter for the function. Have you tried calling `acronym()` without any parameter? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: In prog_replace_callback acronym was called in the form 'acronym'. nothing was used here to replace $matches either. That bugs me the most.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php, Example #2

Comment: In the code you posted, the function `acronym()` is never called explicitly. It is called by [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) as it is described in the documentation, once for every match of the `regex` in the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) function is written in that way, that it calls the function with a well defined argument. See the manual of this function:

> A callback that will be called and passed an array of matched elements in the subject string. The callback should return the replacement string. This is the callback signature:
>
> ```
> handler ( array $matches ) : string
> ```

So your function `acronym()` will get an array with the matches from the regex. Keep in mind that you are not calling the `acronym()` function by yourself, the function `preg_replace_callback()` does that for you (with the argument defined in the documentation).